# explorer api gives diffrent result sets with same permission access token

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have a web page calling me/feed.

The result set I got is different from using api explorer.

I debugged both access_tokens, they have same access rights.

However, if I used access token created by explorer in my web page(hard code), then I got the same result as api explorer.

below are screenshot for those two access_tokens, could not see any difference apart from application id

[**explorer token screen shot**](http://lbm.co.uk/exlporerToken.png)

[**My own app token screen shot**](http://lbm.co.uk/myOwnAppToken.png)

Any ideas please?

```
Belows are code about I obtains my own token

FB.init({
appId: '138930956203643',                       
channelUrl: '//www.lbm.co.uk/channel.htm',           
cookie: true,
status: true,
xfbml: true,
oauth: true
});



FB.login(function (response) {
if (response.authResponse) {
// alert('Authorization result: ' + response.status);
access_token = response.authResponse.accessToken;
uid = response.authResponse.userID;
$("#loginbutton").hide();
$("#logoutbutton").show();
getUserInfo(); // Get User Information.
getLikes();
} else {
alert('Authorization result: ' + response.status);
}
}, { scope: 'user_likes, email, user_friends,read_stream, export_stream' });
```

Then I call get feed

```
$.get('https://graph.facebook.com/' + uid + '/feed?

method=GET&format=json&suppress_http_code=1&access_token='+ access_token, getFeedNext, 
"json");
```

Note, for same code, if I replace access_token with the one from explorer, it returns same result

Comment: How is it different what is missing

Comment: exlorer returns different object structure, say if my friend post somthing on my wall and I made comment about the post, the explorer returns my friend post as top level and then comment as a child of that post. My own token returns two of them at same level and there is no link between them.

Comment: The message is different as well. My own token returns something like Message: "every british likes football" on Kevin Taylor's timeline. While the explorer token just returns Message: "every british likes football"

Comment: explorer token returns data array of size 4, but as mentioned above, each data could has other feed as child, my own token returns data array of size 13, with no link between them